# Duplicates while doing 5 multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

I have 5 tables I need to merge with the max prep_attempt.  I keep getting duplicates and I don't understand why. If a student attended the course more than once, I like to keep the last attempt.

```
SELECT t1.ssn,
       t1.full_name_concat                AS full_name,
       t2.date_of_birth,
       t2.gender,
       t2.marital_status,
       t2.zip_code,
       t2.academic_level_name,
       t2.academic_level_type,
       t2.academic_method,
       t1.prep_class                      AS RosterPrepClas,
       t1.afsc,
       t1.prep_roster_status,
       t1.prep_attempt                    AS PrepRoster_Attempt,
       t1.prep_entry,
       t1.prep_start_date,
       t1.prep_end_date,
       t1.last_prep_outcome_date,
       t3.weight                          AS inbody_wieght,
       t3.height_full_inches              AS inbody_height,
       t3.test_date_time                  AS inbody_test_date_time,
       t3.bmi_recalc                      AS inbody_bmi_recalc,
       t4.prep_class                      AS OFT_prep_Class,
       t4.uic                             AS oft_uic,
       t4.roster                          AS oft_roster,
       t4.afsc                            AS oft_afsc,
       t4.broadjump_initial_inches        AS oft_broadjump_initial_inches,
       t4.agilityright_initial_seconds    AS oft_agilityright_initial_seconds,
       t4.deadlift_initial_pounds         AS oft_deadlift_initial_pounds,
       t4.pullups_initial                 AS oft_pullups_initial,
       t4.farmerscarry_initial_seconds    AS oft_farmerscarry_initial_seconds,
       t4._300yardshuttle_initial_seconds AS oft_300yardshuttle_initial_seconds,
       t4._1500mfin_initial_seconds       AS oft__1500mfin_initial_seconds,
       t4._3mileruck_initial_seconds      AS oft_3mileruck_initial_seconds,
       t4.initial_complete                AS oft_initial_complete,
       t5.prep_class                      AS past_prepclass,
       t5.iteration                       AS past_iteration,
       t5.pullups                         AS past_pullups,
       t5.situps                          AS past_situps,
       t5.pushups                         AS past_pushups,
       t5.swim_time_secs                  AS past_swimtime,
       t5.run_time_secs                   AS past_run_time
FROM   [sw_prep_roster_cao 21-003] t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN adss_demographiccao_20210414 t2
                    ON t1.ssn = t2.ssn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[inbody_initial_clean_cao_prep_21002] t3
                    ON t1.ssn = t3.ssn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sw_prep_oft_test t4
                    ON t1.ssn = t4.ssn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[swprep_past_cao21-002] t5
                    ON t1.ssn = t5.ssn
       INNER JOIN(SELECT ssn,
                         Max(prep_attempt) AS Max_prep_attempt
                  FROM   [sw_prep_roster_cao 21-003]
                  GROUP  BY ssn,
                            prep_attempt) tm
               ON t1.ssn = tM.ssn
                  AND prep_attempt = tm.max_prep_attempt
WHERE  iteration = 'initial'
```

Comment: sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want only the highest prep_attempt for each ssn, removing the group by on prep_attempt will probably solve your issue.

given this sample

```
    CREATE TABLE #prep
(ssn          INT,
 prep_attempt INT
);

insert into #prep(ssn,prep_attempt)
values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)
```

you would have an expected output of

```
1,3  
2,1  
3,2
```

so you would want this for your table expression

```
SELECT ssn,
       MAX(prep_attempt) AS mx
FROM #prep
GROUP BY ssn;
```

This by itself is ok but when you self join the same table to get other columns as you do with [sw_prep_roster_cao 21-003] then you end up searching through the table twice. this could have performance implications on large tables.

I would suggest looking at the [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function. This would allow to get the highest prer_attempt with only 1 seek/scan of the table. Taking the example above you could do:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ssn,
                prep_attempt,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ssn
                ORDER BY prep_attempt DESC) AS rn
        from #prep)
     SELECT *
     FROM cte
     WHERE rn = 1;
```

we can incorporate this into your original query like so:

```
with cte as (SELECT t1.ssn,
       t1.full_name_concat                AS full_name,
       t2.date_of_birth,
       t2.gender,
       t2.marital_status,
       t2.zip_code,
       t2.academic_level_name,
       t2.academic_level_type,
       t2.academic_method,
       t1.prep_class                      AS RosterPrepClas,
       t1.afsc,
       t1.prep_roster_status,
       t1.prep_attempt                    AS PrepRoster_Attempt,
       t1.prep_entry,
       t1.prep_start_date,
       t1.prep_end_date,
       t1.last_prep_outcome_date,
       t3.weight                          AS inbody_wieght,
       t3.height_full_inches              AS inbody_height,
       t3.test_date_time                  AS inbody_test_date_time,
       t3.bmi_recalc                      AS inbody_bmi_recalc,
       t4.prep_class                      AS OFT_prep_Class,
       t4.uic                             AS oft_uic,
       t4.roster                          AS oft_roster,
       t4.afsc                            AS oft_afsc,
       t4.broadjump_initial_inches        AS oft_broadjump_initial_inches,
       t4.agilityright_initial_seconds    AS oft_agilityright_initial_seconds,
       t4.deadlift_initial_pounds         AS oft_deadlift_initial_pounds,
       t4.pullups_initial                 AS oft_pullups_initial,
       t4.farmerscarry_initial_seconds    AS oft_farmerscarry_initial_seconds,
       t4._300yardshuttle_initial_seconds AS oft_300yardshuttle_initial_seconds,
       t4._1500mfin_initial_seconds       AS oft__1500mfin_initial_seconds,
       t4._3mileruck_initial_seconds      AS oft_3mileruck_initial_seconds,
       t4.initial_complete                AS oft_initial_complete,
       t5.prep_class                      AS past_prepclass,
       t5.iteration                       AS past_iteration,
       t5.pullups                         AS past_pullups,
       t5.situps                          AS past_situps,
       t5.pushups                         AS past_pushups,
       t5.swim_time_secs                  AS past_swimtime,
       t5.run_time_secs                   AS past_run_time,
       row_number() over (partition by ssn order by prep_attempt desc ) as rn
FROM   [sw_prep_roster_cao 21-003] t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN adss_demographiccao_20210414 t2
                    ON t1.ssn = t2.ssn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[inbody_initial_clean_cao_prep_21002] t3
                    ON t1.ssn = t3.ssn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sw_prep_oft_test t4
                    ON t1.ssn = t4.ssn
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[swprep_past_cao21-002] t5
                    ON t1.ssn = t5.ssn
WHERE  iteration = 'initial')

select * 
from  cte 
where rn = 1
```

you can read up more on window functions in the doc for the [over clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)